# Magnetic Strip Reader, Event detector + read card

Tags: javascript, php, windows, magnetic-cards

I'm trying to make a program in Windows 10 that is able to detect when a magnetic card passes through the Magnetic Strip Reader and reads the info that is in the card and puts it in a *log.txt* with the date and time.

So far I made this:

```
<?php
    while(true){
        if(/*event*/){
            $cardRead = /*cardInfo*/;
            $date = date(Y/m/d);
            $time = time(H:i:s);
            $txt = "$date, $time, $cardRead\n";
            $myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
            fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        }
    }
?>
```

1. Is there any code in php or javascript to get the *event* and the *cardInfo*?
2. Is it possible to keep the code running while the computer is turned on?
   What should I put on the *while* condition to achieve it?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're running the PHP code on the computer with the card reader?  Or, is this web-based?

Comment: @Brad It's intended to keep it running on the computer with the card reader.